# How do I push CSV file from blob storage to Azure Cosmos DB for Apache Cassandra?

Tags: azure, cassandra, azure-blob-storage

I am not able to push my csv file which is in blob storage to Azure Cosmos DB for Apache Cassandra

I haven't tried anything yet, I am not able to find any proper material

Comment: So are you trying to load a table from a CSV?  Or are you trying to store an entire CSV file in a BLOB column?  It's not clear.

Comment: I am trying to upload whole csv file and its around 8 gb

Comment: and i am trying to load table from a CSV

Answer (score 0):

The CQL `blob` type is designed for storing small images or a short string since our general recommendation is to limit the blob size to less than 1MB.

For this reason we don't recommend that you store files in Cassandra. Instead, continue using the blob storage and only save the metadata such as the blob URL in Cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To load data from a CSV file into Cassandra, you have two options.  There's DSBulk or the cqlsh `COPY` command.

- [cqlsh COPY](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/tools/cqlsh.html#copy-from)

From within cqlsh:

```
> COPY stackoverflow.nerd_holidays (year_bucket, event_date, id, name)
  FROM 'nerd_holidays.csv' WITH DELIMITER = '|' AND HEADER = TRUE;
```

- [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/dsbulkLoad.html)

You can download DSBulk from here: https://downloads.datastax.com/#bulk-loader

```
dsbulk load -url nerd_holidays.csv -k stackoverflow -t nerd_holidays -header true
            -m 'year_bucket=year_bucket, event_date=event_date, id=id, name=name'
```

Either one should work, but with an 8GB file, I'd kind of lean toward DSBulk.